# Productos no vendidos en una fecha dada variable

Tags: sql

Hola buenas tardes tengo esa consigna y no estoy pudiendo resolver la consulta: Productos no vendidos en una fecha dada variable

Estos son los productos vendidos para el 16 - 04 - 2011

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debería listar todos los productos que no sean estos. Dejo un Ejemplo de la tabla de productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi consulta me trae los siguientes resultados inconsistentes, porque por ejemplo no me trae el producto Id=3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es este valor en la fila 3: **`359`** antes de la fecha? ¿De qué tipo es esa columna en tu base de datos? ¿Qué SGBD estás usando? Convendría que pongas la etiqueta correspondiente en la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] y mejora la pregunta.

Comment: Ya te detalle todo lo mas Posible muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda y aporte

Comment: `@fecha` es `datetime`. Si se vendieron a las `2011-04-16 09:15:00.000` ya no es igual que el `dateTime` que has definido. Deberías de comparar la columna con una fecha. Cast(Columna as date) = Cast(@fecha as date). O columna >= Cast(@fecha as date) And Columna < Dateadd(day,1,@fecha). Para que coja el rango entre las 00:00 horas del día filtrado, por eso mayor o igual, y menor que el dia siguiente.

Comment: Gracias por ayudar @Javifer2 El tema que como muestro en los ejemplos las ventas se realizan a las 00 todas, ninguna venta del registro tiene el campo hora. Para mi la clave esta en la forma de visualizar los datos de la tabla Product. Revise lo que me enviaste y me sigue pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debería de responder a la pregunta, puesto que no has dado un detalle apropiado. Has pegado imágenes que no el texto de la consulta, y obligas a todo el que quiera ayudarte a teclear el mismo código.

No obstante.

Lo primero, la base de datos parece AdventureWorks. Yo tengo la version 2019 y los datos me parecen los mismos. Por tanto.

```
DECLARE @FECHA Datetime;
Set @FECHA = '20110416'
Select pod.*, poh.OrderDate from Production.Product Prod 
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod On Prod.ProductID = pod.ProductID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh ON poh.PurchaseOrderID = pod.PurchaseOrderID
Where
poh.OrderDate >= Cast(@FECHA as date)
And
poh.OrderDate < DATEADD(day,1,@fecha);
```

[image: Res1]

El día 16, no hay producto 3.

Por otro lado. No puedes asegurar que tú login va a procesar las fechas como datetime usando '2011-04-16 00:00:00.000'.

[image: Res2]

Fíjate que en la imagen es exactamente mi consulta anterior, pero usando el literal largo, que tú has expuesto.

En el enunciado te dicen fecha dada. No unidad de tiempo. Por tanto si te dan '2011-04-16 09:00:00.012' debería de devolverte lo mismo.

Por último, en mi consulta ya tengo los productos vendidos en la fecha, usando la relación más lógica que es `INNER JOIN` entre las 3 tablas. Por tanto ahí ya entran las muchas opciones que hay de hacerlo. Usando Not In, como ya has expuesto.

```
DECLARE @FECHA Datetime;
Set @FECHA = '20110416';

Select p.* FROM Production.Product As p
Where ProductID not In
(
    Select pod.ProductID 
    From Production.Product Prod 
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod On Prod.ProductID = pod.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh ON poh.PurchaseOrderID = pod.PurchaseOrderID
    Where
    poh.OrderDate >= Cast(@FECHA as date)
    And
    poh.OrderDate < DATEADD(day,1,@fecha)
) Order by ProductId
```

[image: Res3]

Observa que **los alias** de las tablas en los conjuntos **interior y exterior**, **no se repiten**. No es un buen camino, porque te puedes encontrar con problemas, donde tú crees que la consulta esta referenciando a un conjunto y el motor encuentra otro punto. Tampoco deberías de usar alias poco significativos, como he realizado yo para esta demo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Javi. Realmente es mi primer post en StackOverFlow. voy a ir mejorando para dar mayor facilidad en mis consultas. Saludos